# Column data masking security problem

Tags: security, db2, db2-luw, row-level-security, data-masking

In Db2 v11.5.7 on Linux I have simple table:

```
create table admin.patient_data (
patientid int not null primary key,
patient_name varchar(10),
illness varchar(15),
doctor_name varchar(10)
);

insert into admin.patient_data values (1, 'Alice', 'illness A', 'DOCTOR1');
insert into admin.patient_data values (2, 'Bob', 'illness B', 'DOCTOR2');
select * from admin.patient_data;
```

Result:

```
PATIENTID   PATIENT_NAME ILLNESS         DOCTOR_NAME
----------- ------------ --------------- ----------
          1 Alice        illness A       DOCTOR1
          2 Bob          illness B       DOCTOR2
```

Column ILLNESS is sensitive data. I would like to allow this column to be displayed only if column DOCTOR_NAME matches Db2 logged-in user.

```
create mask admin.patient_data on admin.patient_data
   for column illness return
   case when doctor_name = USER then illness else 'Masked data' end
   enable;
alter table admin.patient_data activate column access control;
```

Now user DOCTOR1 connects to database and checks the data with:

```
select * from admin.patient_data
```

it is returned:

```
PATIENTID   PATIENT_NAME ILLNESS         DOCTOR_NAME
----------- ------------ --------------- -----------
          1 Alice        illness A       DOCTOR1
          2 Bob          Masked data     DOCTOR2
```

In row PATIENTID=2 column ILLNESS is expected to be masked.

But doctor is educated, so he/she knows all the illnesses and now target "illness B"

```
db2 "select * from admin.patient_data where illness = 'illness B'"
```

and it gets:

```
PATIENTID   PATIENT_NAME ILLNESS         DOCTOR_NAME
----------- ------------ --------------- -----------
          2 Bob          Masked data     DOCTOR2
```

Field ILLNESS is still marked as expected, but now because of where conditional DOCTOR1 knows that patient Bob has "illness B".

I expected that end-users could filter by values they are returned with where condition. That is: "illness A" and "Marked data".

Is there some simple solution to prevent this? I expect to have no record returned for last select statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [Working As Designed™](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-create-mask):

> The application of enabled column masks does not interfere with the operations of other clauses within the statement such as the `WHERE`, `GROUP BY`, `HAVING`, `SELECT DISTINCT`, and `ORDER BY`. The rows returned in the final result table remain the same, except that the values in the resulting rows might be masked by the column masks.

If you want to prevent access to specific rows, you'll need to activate row access control and define the required row permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Masking is done pretty late in the process, before returning data to end-user, way after WHERE condition is executed.

If the requirement is to strictly do the masking on database level (and not on application level) like all doctors have to have access to all of the patient names, then I see no other option then redesign ER model. This kind of kills the main "marketing" idea masking to be applied on top of existing tables.

First option is to use views instead of data masking and applications access views instead of tables.

Second option is to separate sensitive and non-sensitive data in separate tables. Like having "patientid", "patient_name", "doctor_name" in "patient" table and separate patient-illness relationship in separate table with "patientid" and "illness" fields. Or having "patientid", "patient_name", "doctor_name" and new field "illnessid" in "patient" table and illnessid and illness in new illness table. Then alongside of column masking also use row access control in this two separated tables.